# alfresco document preview on document library

Tags: alfresco, faceted-search, document-library

The document preview widget `AlfDocumentPreview`  is used on `Alfreso` faceted search page. 
I want preview document on document list page. 
What is the best way to achieve this ?

Is  it possible to use this widget in a webscript that i can call from document library page and display the result on popup ?

Edit :  There may be   another way to display preview popup without using AlfDocumentPreview  widget ?

I'm using `Alfresco`  5.0.d version 
thank you

Comment: do you want a list of your document, i mean the document that you stored on your `Alfresco`.

Comment: @YagamiLight what i want to do is to preview each document on document library page (by clicking on the thumbnail) exactly like on faceted-search page. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: to preview it in your application in case yes which language you use

Comment: What do you mean by language? do you mean programming language ?  if so i'd like to use JavaScript. As document library doesn't  use aikau  library i don't know how to display the preview on popup. just for information i'm using alfresco native  document library  page.